# pyqt icon overlap with word

Tags: pyqt

This is what happens:

[image]

code here:

```
self.connectAction = createAction(
    self, "设备连接(&C)", self.setupDevice, 
    icon_id = QStyle.SP_DialogNoButton)
```

and this the createAction:

```
def createAction(parent,
                 text,
                 slot=None,
                 shortcut=None,
                 icon=None,
                 tip=None,
                 checkable=False,
                 signal="triggered()",
                 whatis=None,
                 icon_id=None):
    action = QAction(text, parent)
    if icon:
        if isinstance(icon, QIcon):
            action.setIcon(icon)
        else:
            action.setIcon(QIcon(":/%s.png" % icon))
    if icon_id:
        action.setIcon(app.style().standardIcon(icon_id))
    if slot:
        connect(action, signal, slot)
    return action
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found my problem, I set qt stylesheet, and it cause this problem.